# Why isn't my invitation system working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create an invitation system where only users who received who an invite can sign up. Users who sign up can generate an invite code for their friends. Each invite should belong to a user.

Here's the controller:

```
class InvitesController < ApplicationController
def new
    @invite = current_user.invites.new
end
def create
    @user = current_user
    @invite = @user.invites.create
    @invite.code = rand(1000..9000) 
  end
end
```

The user model:

```
has_many :invites
```

In the index:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
<%= form_for @invite, remote: true do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
    <%= f.submit 'post', class: '', name: 'post' %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

In the routes:

```
resources :invites 
resources :users do
resources :invites 
end
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `add_user_id_to_invites' for main:Object
    from (irb):6
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.0/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.0/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.0/lib/spring/application.rb:191:in `block in serve'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.0/lib/spring/application.rb:161:in `fork'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.0/lib/spring/application.rb:161:in `serve'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.0/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.0/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.0/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'2.3.0 :007 >
```

when I

```
rails generate migration add_user_id_to_invites
```

Comment: What is the specific problem you are having? Is there an error? Are you seeing unexpected behavior? Please be more specific about your question so we can better help answer it. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that, just added the error.

Comment: No worries! The error indicates that the `Invite` model does not have an attribute or database column for `user_id`. What does your `db/schema.rb` tell you? Does the `user_id` column exist for the `invites` table? Did you already create a migration for this? Perhaps you just forgot to run it.

Comment: I get NameError: undefined local variable or method `add_user_id_to_invites' for main:Object when I try to

Comment: Please include that error and the associated migration above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
rails g migration AddUserRefToInvites user:references
```

Which generates a user_id column and appropriate index:

```
class AddUserRefToInvites < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_reference :invites, :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks man, but it solved the problem but I its returning #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []> when I request any invite, like @user.invites.all. Do you know why?

Comment: Are you getting that in your console? If so, looks like you don't have any user invites... Since the relation is empty, Rails just gives back the object type.

Comment: I checked in the console and I did create invites.

Comment: Please share your code in a new question or post your repo.

Comment: Thanks man, it worked now for some reason, maybe I forgot to restart the server or something.